# php/ajax browser problem

Tags: php, javascript, ajax

This could be considered a browser problem. It works in firefox, but not IE or Chrome:

http://robotslacker.com/test.php

the php file it's posting to is simply outputting a number. If you load it in Chrome it loads at 99.

So the question is, how can i achieve the same affect on chrome/ie

Comment: You really need to post some code to give us a clue. :-)

Comment: Seconded. We need to see some code.

Comment: The code is in the source of the page he linked.

Answer (score 0):

This works (in my version of Chrome)...but hangs up the browser for quite a while.

```
function doStuff() {
    $.ajax({
        type: 'POST',
        url: '/ajax_html_echo/',
        data: {
            i:i
        },
        success: function(resp) {
            $("p").html(i);
        },
        dataType: "html",
        async:false
    });    
}

var i = 0, timerId = setInterval(function() {
    doStuff();
    if(++i == 10) clearInterval(timerId);
}, 100);
```

Comment: oops - you'll have to put the url back :) demo is [here](http://jsfiddle.net/UyYuZ/)

Answer (score 0):

If you do the test in chrome, you'll notice that it pauses for a while before the 99 is displayed. Most likely it is working properly, it is just NOT displaying the intermediate 1-98 until the POST loop is done. This is on v5.0.375.125 (latest/greatest to date).

If you run the test in opera, it only outputs odd numbers.